# group by col_1,cube(col_2,col_3) producing error in pyspark

Tags: pyspark, group-by, apache-spark-sql

I have the following view (`dfview`) in pyspark -

```
+----+-----+-------+
|roll|grade|subject|
+----+-----+-------+
|   1|    A|  Maths|
|   1|    A|   Chem|
|   1|    B|    Phy|
|   2|    A|  Maths|
|   2|    B|   Chem|
|   2|    B|    Phy|
+----+-----+-------+
```

I am running the following query in `spark.sql` -

```
spark.sql('''
          select
            grouping(roll),
            grouping(grade),
            grouping(subject),
            count(*)
          from
            dfview
          group by roll,cube(grade,subject)
''').show()
```

I am getting the following error -

```
AnalysisException: grouping() can only be used with GroupingSets/Cube/Rollup;
'Aggregate [roll#19400, cube(grade#19401, subject#19402)], [grouping(roll#19400) AS grouping(roll)#19420, grouping(grade#19401) AS grouping(grade)#19421, grouping(subject#19402) AS grouping(subject)#19422, count(1) AS count(1)#19423L]
+- SubqueryAlias dfview
   +- LogicalRDD [roll#19400, grade#19401, subject#19402], false
```

However I tried a similar form of query in `oracle, 19c` and it executed properly. Does pyspark not support this form of `group by`? I am using `pyspark 3.1.2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Syntax is different in [Spark-SQL](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-ref-syntax-qry-select-groupby.html).

```
GROUP BY grade, subject WITH CUBE
```

you can use `grouping()` function only for the columns which you used in GROUP BY clause.

Comment: Thanks @Mohana B C. First I understand the correct syntax now. There is a shortcoming though with "GROUP BY grade, subject WITH CUBE". The reason I intended to use "group by roll,cube(grade,subject)" was that the maximum level of super-aggregation would be by "roll" and I can keep "roll"" in the view of select. With your solution the level of super-aggregation will be proper. But "roll" cannot be in the view portion. Any solution for that. Please note I would like to avoid doing the filtering in "HAVING" clause because that is not saving the effort.