# grouping() shows behaviour in pyspark not consistent with oracle

Tags: pyspark, group-by, apache-spark-sql

I am using the following view (`dfview`) -

```
+----+-----+-------+
|roll|grade|subject|
+----+-----+-------+
|   1|    A|  Maths|
|   1|    A|   Chem|
|   1|    B|    Phy|
|   2|    A|  Maths|
|   2|    B|   Chem|
|   2|    B|    Phy|
+----+-----+-------+
```

I am running the following query in `pyspark` -

```
spark.sql('''
          select
          roll,
            grouping(roll),
            grouping(grade),
            grouping(subject),
            count(*)
          from
            dfview
          group by cube(roll,grade,subject)
          having
            (grouping(roll) = 0
            and count(*) > 1)
''').show()
```

I am getting an error -

```
AnalysisException: Column of grouping (roll#19400) can't be found in grouping columns roll#19572,grade#19573,subject#19574
```

I think this is due to the introduction of the column `roll` in the select view portion. This sort of query does not produce any error in `oracle 19c` though. Is it a shortcoming of `pyspark 3.1.2`, that I am using. A similar discrepancy of `pyspark` with `oracle sql` behaviour in relation to `grouping`, I highlighted in the [following question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68900808/group-by-col-1-cubecol-2-col-3-producing-error-in-pyspark).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to assign aliases to the columns that are referenced in the `having` clause

```
spark.sql(""" select
            roll,
            grouping(roll) as gr_roll,
            grouping(grade),
            grouping(subject),
            count(*) as ct
          from
            dfview
          group by cube(roll,grade,subject)
          having
            gr_roll = 0
            and ct > 1""").show()

# +----+-------+---------------+-----------------+---+
# |roll|gr_roll|grouping(grade)|grouping(subject)| ct|
# +----+-------+---------------+-----------------+---+
# |   1|      0|              1|                1|  3|
# |   2|      0|              0|                1|  2|
# |   1|      0|              0|                1|  2|
# |   2|      0|              1|                1|  3|
# +----+-------+---------------+-----------------+---+
```

or use backticks like `` `grouping(roll)` `` and `` `count(1)` `` if you do not want to use aliases